# link failure - undefined references to graphical functions

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I have working C++/Windows program compiled with Visual Studio 2008. The program consists of just two .cpp files. I am now attempting to compile and link it using MinGW. So far I have successfully compiled both source files without error, but now when I link them with the command...

```
g++ -o program.exe file1.o file2.o
```

... I get many instances of "undefined reference to.." assorted graphics related functions like:

```
GetStockObject, SelectObject, MoveTo, LineTo, SetPixel, TextOut, BitBlt, CreatePen etc.
```

I am not getting undefined references for any other types of windows call. Clearly I have missed something in my linker command line, but cant work out what.

Comment: Look at the compiler command line in VS2008 and add all missing libraries to yours

Comment: You need to add library references to your project

Comment: In vis Studio I can see  gdi32.lib on the commend line. This is an obvious candidate. But there is no file of that name within the mingw installation directory or subdirectories. However there is a libgdi32.a file within the c:\mingw\lib directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this spans two (similar) prior answers, I'll add it as a separate answer, rather than as duplicate comments on those preceding answers.

Better, rather than jumping in and adding "-lgdi32", you should first add the "-mwindows" option; this tells GCC that you are building a Windows application, (its default is a "console" application type), and so causes it to automatically bind a number of additional graphics device interface specific libraries, (one of which is gdi32.dll).  Only if adding this option still fails to resolve all symbols need you worry about what other non-default libraries may be needed.

Comment: Right! Well, Keith should know, he is the MinGW32 Maintainer. Upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

All these functions are located in `Gdi32.dll`. You need to link `Gdi32.lib` to make them work. You can try:

`g++ -o program.exe file1.o file2.o -L MinGW\lib -lgdi32`

By the way, Microsoft documents each function extensively and names the appropriate library. For example: [GetStockObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it like this:
For each undefined reference, look up that function at Microsoft Developer Network documentation. In your case, google for

GetStockObject msdn

The MSDN page describing the function contains at the bottom a section "Requirements". Here it lists required DLLs that you need to link to.

In case of GetStockObject, that's Gdi32.dll

Extend your command line to include -lGdi32

Retry the linking and repeat for any remaining undefined references.